# Can't format USB stick on Kubuntu

Tags: partitioning, usb, kde

I've been trying to format my USB stick through Kubuntu's partition manager, I can create a new partition table normally but when I try to create a new NTFS partition it just shows this error message:
[image: .]

This probably has already been answered but I couldn't find anything. Thanks in advance to whoever knows how to solve this

Comment: I would suggest using Windows to create NTFS partitions since it's a proprietary file system from Microsoft for Windows.  To rule out the possibility that the problem is with your Ubuntu installation, you can also create bootable media for Ubuntu and try to use the Disks application in a live session.  If you can't format the disk in a live session using a different app, and if you also can't format the disk on Windows - the disk is probably dead

Comment: @Nmath I already thought of doing it using Windows but I don't have any Windows machines right now, and I was able to format and create another bootable USB with Ubuntu too so the problem doesn't seem to be with the disk, I'll probably have to wait and get someone else's Windows PC but thanks for the help anyways.

Comment: If you aren't going to use the volume with Windows, why use NTFS?